# wsgen not creating wsdl file

Tags: google-app-engine, jax-ws, wsgen

I was following http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/soap.html to create a Web Service in Google App Engine. After reach item no 4, where i need to run wsgen to generate wsdl file for my Web Service, I found the sample syntax was given for Linux. I managed to find the syntax for Window but when i run it, It creates a package called jaxws but no xsd and wsdl file created. It only creates package `com.example.jaxws` and no other java files created in side the package.

What I did:

1st I compile the java file in CMD

```
C:\Smartag_Eclipse_Project\HelloSOAPServer\src>javac com\example\Greeter.java
```

2nd I run wsgen

```
C:\Smartag_Eclipse_Project\HelloSOAPServer\src>wsgen -cp . com.example.Greeter -
wsdl
```

Appreciate if someone could help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

`wsgen -cp C:\Smartag_Eclipse_Project\HelloSOAPServer\war\WEB-INF\classes -wsdl -keep -r C:\Smartag_Eclipse_Project\HelloSOAPServer\war -d` `C:\Smartag_Eclipse_Project\HelloSOAPServer\war\WEB-INF\classes -s`   `C:\Smartag_Eclipse_Project\HelloSOAPServer\src  com.example.Greeter`